# Knockout.js disconnect between the bound display and underlying values

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following markup:

```
fare: <input name="fare" type="text" data-bind="value: fare " />
cash <input name="cash_amt" type="text" data-bind="value: cash()" />
charge <input name="charge_amt" type="text" data-bind="value: charge()" />
coupon <input name="coupon_amt" type="text" data-bind="value: prepaid()" />
```

with all bound variables observable, and a subscription on fare that triggers the following function:

```
self.setPayment = function () {
if (self.payment_contract().terms == null) {
    self.cash(self.fare());
    self.charge(null);
    self.prepaid(null);
} else if (self.payment_contract().terms == 'charge') {
    self.cash(null);
    self.charge(self.fare());
    self.prepaid(null);
} else if (self.payment_contract().terms == 'prepaid') {
    self.cash(null);
    self.charge(null);
    self.prepaid(self.fare());
}
```

Full context and code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6mwxq9g/8/)

Assuming the page loaded with a charge payment type, everything loads as expected (the full fare amount is in both the fare input and the charge input).  If I add $1.00 to the cash input, then change the amount of the fare, I expect that it would reset the cash input to null, and populate the charge input with the fare amount.  It is actually populating the charge box with the new value, but is not resetting the cash input to null.  When I log the value for `self.cash()` after adding a value to the input, it logs as being null.  There seems to be a disconnect between the bound display and underlying values, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your data-bind is `value: cash()` not `value: cash`.  (Ditto for `charge()` and `prepaid()` )

Most bindings are read-only, so the parenthesis are essentially optional.  `text: foo()` and `text: foo` will have the same functionality; but for data-bindings that need to be writable, it's important that you bind it to the observable itself, not the result of invoking the observable.

When you do `value: cash()` the thing that gets bound to value is essentially:

```
ko.computed(function() {
    return cash();
});
```

The input gets initialized to the value of that function; but then changes to the input don't get written back to the `cash` observable, because the computed is read-only.

Comment: Very helpful explanation, I think that knowledge will help with some other issues I am having as well.  Thank you.